# Spectral decomposition matrix proof

Tags: matrices, svd

Suppose we have a square matrix $A$ with singular value decomposition $A=U\Sigma V'$.

How can we show the equation 
$$\begin{bmatrix}0 & A^T \\ A & 0 \end{bmatrix}=\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}
\begin{bmatrix}V & V\\ U & -U\end{bmatrix}
\begin{bmatrix}\Sigma&0\\0&\Sigma\end{bmatrix} \frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}
\begin{bmatrix}V^T &U^T\\ V^T &-U^T\end{bmatrix}
?$$

Comment: Fixed typo, thanks.

Comment: and its SVD decomposition is $\begin{bmatrix}0 & A^T \\ A & 0 \end{bmatrix}=
\begin{bmatrix}0 & U^T\\ U & 0\end{bmatrix}
\begin{bmatrix}\Sigma&0\\0&\Sigma\end{bmatrix} 
\begin{bmatrix}V &0\\ 0 &V^T\end{bmatrix}
$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Something is wrong with the identity.

Block matrices with blocks of the same size can be multiplied as if you had numbers:
$$
\begin{split}\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}
\begin{bmatrix}V & V \\ U & -U\end{bmatrix}
\begin{bmatrix}\Sigma&0\\0&\Sigma\end{bmatrix} \frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}
\begin{bmatrix}V^T &U^T\\ V^T &-U^T\end{bmatrix}
&=\frac12
\begin{bmatrix}V\Sigma & V\Sigma\\ U\Sigma & -U\Sigma\end{bmatrix}
\begin{bmatrix}V^T &U^T\\ V^T &-U^T\end{bmatrix}\\
&=
\begin{bmatrix}V\Sigma V^T & 0\\ 0 & U\Sigma U^T\end{bmatrix}.
\end{split}
$$

You probably want instead:
$$
\begin{split}\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}
\begin{bmatrix}V & V \\ U & -U\end{bmatrix}
\begin{bmatrix}\Sigma&0\\0&\Sigma\end{bmatrix} \frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}
\begin{bmatrix}V^T &U^T\\ \color{red}{-V^T} &\color{red}{U^T}\end{bmatrix}
&=\frac12
\begin{bmatrix}V\Sigma & V\Sigma\\ U\Sigma & -U\Sigma\end{bmatrix}
\begin{bmatrix}V^T &U^T\\ -V^T &U^T\end{bmatrix}\\
&=
\begin{bmatrix}0 & V\Sigma U^T\\ U\Sigma V^T & 0\end{bmatrix}\\
&=
\begin{bmatrix}0 & A^T\\ A & 0\end{bmatrix}.
\end{split}
$$